# how to Implement Cruise Control with QTP?

Tags: .net, cruisecontrol.net, qtp, cruisecontrol

I would like to integrate QTP with Cruise Control, which I have done so far, i'm stuck at the reporting part.

I would like to somehow report back to Cruise Control with the results, how can I accomplish this? Please help?

Answer (score 4):

I remember there was a useful series on how to integrate CCNET with various build and testing 
tools including QTP. This is what I bookmarked:

[Part 1: Continuous Integration using MSBuild, CruiseControl.NET, FxCop, NUnit, NCover + Subversion - From the software development trenches](http://dotnet.org.za/cjlotz/archive/2007/04/04/part-1-continuous-integration-using-msbuild-cruisecontrol-net-fxcop-nunit-ncover-subversion.aspx)

But somehow it seems to have vanished. Today I found the [updated version](http://fromthedevtrenches.blogspot.com/2009/11/continuous-integration-from-theory-to.html) by accident. It doesn't include QTP integration anymore but it has a link to the [original version as PDF file](http://sites.google.com/site/fromthedevtrenches/downloads/ContinuousIntegration-FromTheorytoPractice.pdf?attredirects=0&d=1).