# How to develop a Nightly Builder

Tags: java, junit, testing, qtp, nightly-build

I was told to create a tool like a Nightly Builder for a JUnit project. It's a client-server project with oracle database.The tests are based on QTP. Also there is a test interface written on C#. The tester can click on the interface to choose which tests to run and get a report from each test. So I have to make this procedure automated. So what tools should I use? 
Thanks in advance
Best regards

Comment: Why not use one of the excellent existing systems that do everything already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) or like tool?  We use this at my work and it was easy to get up and running with Junit and/or TestNG.  Other tools to consider are buildbot, continuum, hudson, etc.   (Go to google and type "cruisecontrol vs" and see a bunch of other auto builder tools.)  Then see how they handle nightly builds.... here's a [reference](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CC/CruiseControl+Scheduling+Scenarios) for CruiseControl.

Comment: Do you know how to use CruiseControl with QTP? If so please answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601325/how-to-implement-cruise-control-with-qtp

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). In the quart scheduling xml file you can specify it to build your project. In your project you should have junit test cases execute whenever a build happens. This way you can achieve a daily build process. If your project already utilizes Spring framework then you can use the spring job scheduler helper library too (it's a wrapper around quartz).

Ideally you should use [hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) to manage the daily builds but I am not sure if your organization utilizes it or not.

Hope this helps.