# How to implement Cruise Control with QTP

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, qtp

I would like to integrate QTP with Cruise Control.net and dont know how to do that so can any one please let me know step by step how to do it or if any url that says about it.

I have a qtp and cc.net on my local machine. Do I require anything else as I just want to implement qtp with CC.net?

So it will be really helpful if any one can guide me step by step how to implement QTP with Cruise control.net.

Comment: Hey can any one answer this question..?

Comment: What research (google) have you done so far?

Comment: Find my answer on a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601325/how-to-implement-cruise-control-with-qtp/2985505#2985505).

Answer (score 1):

1. figure out how to [run your QTP scripts from the command line](http://motevich.blogspot.ch/2008/04/how-to-run-qtp-test-from-command-line.html).
2. setup a CC.net project that runs your QTP scripts
3. use the [file merge task](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/File_Merge_Task) to merge the xml output into your build log
4. write a XSL stylesheet that converts the XML output into HTML